# Store data of JSON response into multiple variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, laravel-5.5

I have been obtaining the json response the same as i needed, but it is in data response. i want to store it in different variables so that i can use it in javascript the way i need to.

function which is passing the json data is:

```html
 public function get_Ajax(Request $request)
    {
        $b_id = $request->input('b_id');

            $pays = Booking::find($b_id);
            foreach ($pays->payments as $pay) {
                $paymentss[] = $pay->payment;
                $p_dates[] = $pay->created_at->format('d-M-Y');
            }

        return response()->json([
            $paymentss,
            $p_dates
        ]);
    }
```

Button which is calling the function is:

```html
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-href="#full-width" href="#full-width" onclick="showdetail({{$book->id}})" style="background-color: #224777">View Payments Schedule</button>
```

and the function which is obtaining the response

```js
function showdetail(b_id) {
$.get('/my-account/get_payments?b_id='+b_id, function(data){
alert(data)
});
}
```

kindly let me know how i can split the data into the two variables.

Comment: How does `data` look like?

Comment: Where are you wanting to split it?  If you mean split it in the php, then no, you wouldn't do that as if the response is expecting json back, simply returning a json response with two objects is the easiest approach.  All the javascript has to do with such a response is var x = response[0]; and var y = response[1]; then

Comment: I want to split the data in the function "showdetail" so that i can use it further.

Comment: the response of the data is190000,190000,18000,20-Apr-2018,20-Apr-2018,20-Apr-2018

Comment: From the snippet you gave, is `return response()->json` not being given an array of two arrays?  try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` in your showdetail and tell us what it prints out.

Comment: by using console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
i got the response [[190000,190000,18000],["20-Apr-2018","20-Apr-2018","20-Apr-2018"]]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you say "use it in the way I need to" what exactly do you mean? Are you altering the data? If not then you can just pass the JSON object around however you want and it'll be fine, no need to do anything more than

```
function showdetail(b_id) {
  $.get('/my-account/get_payments?b_id='+b_id, function(data){
    let var1 = data,
        var2 = data;
  });
}
```

If you're going to be editing the data in different ways the easiest way to copy JSON is just to stringify and then parse it like so

```
function showdetail(b_id) {
  $.get('/my-account/get_payments?b_id='+b_id, function(data){
    let var1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
        var2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
}
```

Comment: it did work ultimately, thanks for the response, appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a JSON object.

For example:

```
$jsonObj= array('Payments' => $paymentss,
                'PaymentDates' => $p_dates);
```

Which will create the following JSON:

```
{
    "Payments": payments,
    "PaymentDates": payDates
}
```

And in the response function:

```
var payments = data.Payments;
var paymentDates = data.PaymentDates;
```

Comment: can u please guide how to create json object instead of array? as i don't have much experience with objects creation or usage.